# duvida com select sum() Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

tenho essas duas tabelas, janeiro e fevereiro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

cada campo corresponde ao dia do mes, d1= dia 01, etc. Preciso criar uma select que mostre o valor mensal de cada plano de conta, exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como seria essa sql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu modelo é ruim faça um do tipo

## Tabela

Data
Valor

Com [funcões de data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) fica fácil totalizar por mês , ano , semana etc.

Answer (score 4):

Tenta usar o seguinte código:

```
SELECT
  SUM(d1 + d2 + d3 + ... + d12) as soma
FROM
  janeiro
```

Comment: Dan, pensei em fazer isso, porem serão 12 tabelas(uma para cada mes), queria saber se teria um sql melhor. E como agruparia os planos de contas?

Comment: Infelizmente da forma que você modelou o banco talvez seja a única maneira (na minha lógica), para agrupar pelo plano, você deve realizar um select puxando o plano e realizando um group by. Seria mais interessante você criar uma única tabela, contendo as colunas: id, valor, mês. Ai você tem apenas uma tabela, seria a forma mais correta nesse exemplo.

Comment: Modelos ruins geram sqls ruins e desnecessariamente complicados.